# Jumping to a special anchor depending on where submit was executed

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, opera

I want to jump to a certain area on a page depending on where a submit button was pressed.

This is what I tried

```
<script>
  function testfunc(e,a)
  {
    if(e && e.keyCode == 13)
      executefunc(a);
  }
  function executefunc( url )
  {
    document.af.action = url;
  }
</script>
<form id="af" ...>
  <div id ="anchor">  
    <input type="search" name="s1" id="name1" value="" onkeypress="return testfunc(event,'test.php?argument#anchor')" />                                                                        
    <button type="submit" name="submit1" value="search" onClick="executefunc('test.php?argument#anchor')">search                                       
    </button>           
  </div>   
  <div id ="anchor2">
    <input type="search" name="s2" id="name2" value="" onkeypress="return testfunc(event,'test.php?argument#anchor2')" />                                                                        
    <button type="submit" name="submit2" value="search" onClick="executefunc('test.php?argument#anchor2')">search                                       
    </button>       
  </div>
    ...   
</form>
```

Goal is to go to the anchor when return is pressed or the button. When the button is pressed, it jumps to the anchor when reloaded but when return in pressed in the field it does not.

Why?

I am using Opera. This should work on all major HTML5 capable browsers.

Comment: You should fix you markup first: `id` of an element must be unique within a page and `name` must be unique within a form.

Comment: @Pavlo fixed. what now?